# Why does the DTFT of unit step function exist?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Using the Discrete time fourier transform formula, the unit step function should transform to:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-jwn}$$

This should be a diverging sum, right? The magnitude of every terms is $1$ for any value of $w$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true it doesn't converge in usual sense. Then I'm afraid you need the theory of distributions. For $z\in \Bbb{C},|z|>1$ let $$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{-n} = \frac1{1-z^{-1}}$$
$f(z)$ is the $Z$ transform of $1_{n \ge 0}$ which is perfectly well-defined on $|z|> 1$.

$f(r e^{it})$ is the DTFT of $r^{-n} 1_{n \ge 0}$,

As $r \to 1^+$, $$r^{-n} 1_{n \ge 0} \to 1_{n \ge 0}$$
Then the DTFT of $1_{n \ge 0}$ is **the limit in the sense of distributions** $$\lim_{r \to 1^+} f(re^{it}) = \lim_{r \to 1^+}\frac1{1-r^{-1}e^{-it}}=\pi  \sum_k \delta(t-2\pi k) + pv(\frac1{1-e^{-it}})$$

where $\sum_k \delta(t-2\pi k)$ is the $2\pi$-periodic Dirac delta whose Fourier coefficients are all $1$ and $pv(\frac1{1-e^{-it}})$ is the principal value of $\frac1{1-e^{-it}}$ defined by $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi pv(\frac1{1-e^{-it}}) \phi(t)dt=\lim_{a \to 0}\int_{-\pi}^{-a}+\int_a^\pi \frac1{1-e^{-it}} \phi(t)dt$$
for all $\phi$ smooth.

> Those things are defined this way so that we can recover $1_{n \ge 0}$ as the Fourier coefficients of $\frac1{2\pi}(\pi  \sum_k \delta(t-2\pi k) + pv(\frac1{1-e^{-it}}))$

Comment: But isn't $\frac{1}{1-e^{-it}}$ single valued? Why do we need a principal value? Also, the source I'm reading gives the answer as (Periodic Dirac delta function + $\frac{1}{1-e^{-it}}$) without any pv

Comment: The Fourier coefficients of $pv(\frac1{1-e^{-it}})$ are well-defined they are $\int_{-\pi}^\pi pv(\frac1{1-e^{-it}}) e^{-int}dt=\lim_{a \to 0}\int_{-\pi}^{-a}+\int_a^\pi \frac1{1-e^{-it}}e^{-int}dt$ whereas $\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac1{1-e^{-it}} e^{-int}dt$ is not due to the non-integrable singularity at $t=0$. This is what the principal value is about : defining a distribution that we can integrate with any smooth function, it is not about single-valued-ness.